# what is the difference between range(n) and *range(n) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

- `print(*range(1,n+1),sep='')`
- `print(range(1,n+1),sep='')`

I am trying to print `123...n` sequence as a whole given an interger `n`,without using any string functions which is a hackerrank question.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-print/problem

What is the difference between line 1 and 2?

Please explain in basic terminology as I am new to python.